# How to query on multiple filters in pymongo's find_one_and_update() method?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to use pymongo's find_one_and_update() method to update some values in mongoDB, but I need to filter based on two different conditions, and this does not seem possible.

I tried passing in a list of filters akin to [{"name": "name"}, {"date": "date}], but this did not work.

Is there no way to filter on multiple conditions with this method? How else can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: can you give sample data and an example of what you want to get from them?

Answer (score 3):

I figured out that the single filter argument can be a query using boolean logic. The solution was:

```
{"$and":[{"name": "name"}, {"date": "date"}]}
```

as the filter argument.

Comment: It is as good as ```find_one({"name": "name"}, {"date": "date"})```. Use this only if you want to use it for ```$or``` where you want either one of the filter to work.

Answer (score 0):

Well for multiple filters,if you need all of them to be in effect, then its just a simple filter dictonary as below:

```
find_one({"name": "name"}, {"date": "date"})
```

However, if you need to have any of those multiple filters to be in effect, then you can use `$or` operator

```
find_one({"$or":[{"name": "name"}, {"date": "date"}]})
```